# Validate Replica Set Data

Tags: mongodb

I am new here and I hope I am posting my question on the right forum. I didn't see where to pick the right forum category for MongoDB..

I have 2 questions -

I am using Mongodb 2.6, and I am in the process of migrating 2 replica sets RS0 & RS1 from a data center to AWS. I have 3 servers on each replica set, making a total of 6 servers. The option that I am using to migrate data to new servers is by expanding the replica sets to the new hardware and then let them catch-up completely before I can remove the nodes on the old hardware from the replica set.

Question-1> How do I validate the data on both replica sets (source & destination) to make sure the data is 100% in sync before I can remove the old replica set from the source? What are the proper commands I can use to check the number of collections and data counts on all collections for all databases I am migrating ?

Question-2> Correct me if I am wrong - My understanding is when using Replica sets, we have to keep odd numbers of members within a RS. Right now I have 3 servers per RS which is fine, but when I add a new member to my current RS, which will be pointing to a new server, I will end up with 4 members - wouldn't that cause a problem ? Should I add 2 members in my RS instead so that I can keep 5 members which is an odd number ?

Thank you so much in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: use rs.status() on any of the replica set members; you can check the status of each member and the optime field (compare with the primary): 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/rs.status/

Question 2: you need an odd number of members because only one member can be elected as primary, and each member can vote for 1 member, so having an even number of members could lead, during the primary member election, to an equal number of votes for two or more members. To have an odd number of members you can set up an arbitet instance: http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/add-replica-set-arbiter/

Answer (score 0):

@Stefano gave you the answer.I would just like to add a few:

**Question 1:**

You can use `rs.status` to check the replica set status.This sort out the primary and secondary clearly.

```
{
    "set" : "replset",
    "date" : ISODate("2015-11-19T15:22:32.597Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "term": NumberLong(1),
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "m1.example.net:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 269,
            "optime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1447946550, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(1)
                     },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-11-19T15:22:30Z"),
            "infoMessage" : "could not find member to sync from",
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1447946549, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2015-11-19T15:22:29Z"),
            "configVersion" : 1,
            "self" : true
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "m2.example.net:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 13,
                     "optime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1447946539, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                     },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-11-19T15:22:19Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-11-19T15:22:31.323Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-11-19T15:22:32.045Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "configVersion" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "m3.example.net:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 13,
                     "optime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1447946539, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                     },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-11-19T15:22:19Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-11-19T15:22:31.325Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-11-19T15:22:31.971Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "configVersion" : 1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

To know the slave delay fire `rs.printSlaveReplicationInfo()`:

```
source: localhost.localdomain:27070
        syncedTo: Mon May 02 2016 12:34:36 GMT+0530 (IST)
        0 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary
source: localhost.localdomain:27072
        syncedTo: Mon May 02 2016 12:34:36 GMT+0530 (IST)
        0 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary
source: localhost.localdomain:27073
        syncedTo: Mon May 02 2016 12:34:36 GMT+0530 (IST)
        0 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary
```

To know more detail about replication catch up in the oplog try  `rs.printReplicationInfo()`:

```
configured oplog size:   700.0038909912109MB
log length start to end: 261920secs (72.76hrs)
oplog first event time:  Fri Apr 29 2016 11:49:16 GMT+0530 (IST)
oplog last event time:   Mon May 02 2016 12:34:36 GMT+0530 (IST)
now:                     Mon May 02 2016 12:49:37 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

**Question 2:**

Odd number replicas facilitates high voting in the election.So in case u have even replica sets you can add `Arbiters`.They are just light weight and do not contain data,they can also reside on any other currently running server.

Hope this helps !!!